# Split sorted array of ISO 8601 dates into new 2d arrays for each day in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I'm trying to split a sorted array containing ISO 8601 (UTC) dates into a 2D array, where each day represents an array containing all of the dates where the year/month/day match.

Example array:

```
let dates = [
  '2019-07-14T08:02:27Z',  
  '2019-07-05T17:22:34Z',  
  '2019-06-25T21:23:30Z',  
  '2019-06-25T16:46:55Z',  
  '2019-06-18T14:14:15Z',  
  '2019-06-18T13:09:07Z'   
];
```

Ideally, the above array would create the following 2D array:

```
let dates = [
  ['2019-07-14T08:02:27Z'],
  ['2019-07-05T17:22:34Z'],
  ['2019-06-25T21:23:30Z', '2019-06-25T16:46:55Z'],
  ['2019-06-18T14:14:15Z', '2019-06-18T13:09:07Z']
];
```

I've tried quite a few approaches but for the sake of providing some code, I substring each array element `date[i].substring(0, 10)` which returns the year/month/day, say `2019-07-14` - since the array is sorted I compare the previous and current element and decide if the element should be added to a new array or not.

```js
  let arr = [], temp = [];
  for (let i = 0, prev = null; i < dates.length; i++) {
    temp.push(dates[i]);

    if (!(dates[i].substring(0, 10) === prev)) {
      arr.push(temp);
      temp = [];
    }
    prev = dates[i].substring(0, 10);
  }
```

Code doesn't work as it is off by one in some cases, e.g:

```
[ '2019-07-14T08:02:27Z' ],
[ '2019-07-10T14:22:04Z' ],
[ '2019-07-09T16:08:22Z' ], // should be in below array
[
  '2019-07-09T15:58:55Z',
  '2019-07-09T14:41:49Z',
  '2019-07-09T14:12:04Z',
  '2019-07-09T14:10:29Z',
  '2019-07-09T13:34:46Z',
  '2019-07-09T13:28:14Z',
  '2019-07-08T15:51:38Z' // conflicting dates
],
[ '2019-07-08T15:45:07Z', '2019-07-07T15:07:47Z' ], // conflicting dates
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do they have to stay strings? Because if you turn them into Date objects first, things become a lot easier. ("pick the right data structure, and your problem stops being one")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce the array by checking the date substring.

```js
let dates = ['2019-07-14T08:02:27Z', '2019-07-05T17:22:34Z', '2019-06-25T21:23:30Z', '2019-06-25T16:46:55Z', '2019-06-18T14:14:15Z', '2019-06-18T13:09:07Z'],
    result = dates.reduce((r, s, i) => {
        if (!i || r[r.length - 1][0].slice(0, 10) !== s.slice(0, 10)) r.push([]);
        r[r.length - 1].push(s);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: If this may help reading: `r` is `accumulatedResult`, `s` is `iteratedElement`, `i` is `iteratedIndex`, `!i` is `true` for the very first iteration only.

Answer (score 1):

Simply maintain a map of all the dates, and keep pushing the dates to the array if they are present in the map, `Object.values()` on the map will give you the desired result, This works fine even when the dates are not sorted:

```js
let dates = [ '2019-07-14T08:02:27Z', '2019-07-05T17:22:34Z', '2019-06-25T21:23:30Z', '2019-06-25T16:46:55Z', '2019-06-18T14:14:15Z', '2019-06-18T13:09:07Z' ];

let resullt = Object.values(dates.reduce((acc,d) => {
  let date = d.substr(0,10);
  (acc[date] = acc[date] || []).push(d);
  return acc;
},{}));

console.log(resullt);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [], temp = [];
  for (let i = 0, prev = null; i < dates.length; i++) {
    if (
      prev &&
      !(dates[i].substring(0, 10) === prev)
    ) {
      arr.push(temp);
      temp = [];
    }
    temp.push(dates[i]);
    prev = dates[i].substring(0, 10);
  }
  arr.push(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function generator to group the dates according to a desired criteria.

This likely is going to be less compact than other solutions, but should be easier to maintain and to read.

Below example acquires two dates at a time and checks whether the current one (first) satisfy the provided criteria against the next one. If it does, it accumulates it and continues, otherwise it yield the previous block and continues the cycle until finished.

Below is the implementation:

```js
let dates = [
  '2019-07-14T08:02:27Z',  
  '2019-07-05T17:22:34Z',  
  '2019-06-25T21:23:30Z',  
  '2019-06-25T16:46:55Z',  
  '2019-06-18T14:14:15Z',  
  '2019-06-18T13:09:07Z'
];

function* groupSimilarDates(dateArr, criteria) {
  var acc = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < dateArr.length; i++) {
    var [currDate, nextDate] = [dateArr[i],dateArr[i+1]];
    if (nextDate) {
      if (criteria(currDate, nextDate)) acc.push(currDate);
      else {
        if (acc.length) {
          acc.push(currDate);
          yield acc, acc = [];
        }
        else yield [currDate];
      }
    }
    else {
      if (criteria(currDate, dateArr[i-1])) acc.push(currDate), yield acc;
      else {
        if (acc.length) yield [acc];
        yield [currDate];
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log([...groupSimilarDates(dates, (a,b) => a.substring(0,10) === b.substring(0,10))]);
```